# input inside absolute div is not responding

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have absolutely positioned an input inside a div element, but the input is unresponsive :

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 48px;">
     <input id="myinput">
</div>
```

To test I tried:

```
$("#myinput").click(function(){
     $(this).focus().select();
});
```

This gives the input focus, but the value still won't change!

Comment: Works fine in Chrome. Do you have more code that may be causing a problem?

Comment: i will reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net/ then i will repost it

Comment: can you add a fiddle so we can see how it's unresponsive?... are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/FY2CF/

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; height: 48px;">
<input id="myinput" type="text" />
</div>


$("#myinput").click(function(e){
 this.select();
});
```

Comment: adding z-index: 1000; fix the problem even if i cant find what object was hiding the input (even with dom inspector)

Comment: that is strange. you can try adding a setTimeout to call the event with 100ms delay, the problem could be caused by some synchronizations issues on the browser.   setTimeout($("#myinput").click(function(){ ....}),100);

Comment: i dont know but adding a very big z-index fix the problem even as i said nothing is hiding thoses inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any js errors and all the files are loaded, try this:

```
$("#myinput").on('click', function () {
  // if you are clicking on it, you do not need to focus()
  $(this).select();
})
```

Comment: the goal is not to select the input, i add this test just to try understand what is happening, i dont know why the input receive all events keydown, click ... but not responding at all

Comment: if the input has a value, .select() will highlight it based on the event listener, in this case we are listening for a click in the input field with an id of "myinput"; the docs might explain it better with examples: https://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: i know my friend, it just a stupid test, because i dont understand what is happening, because if i dont add the click event the input is not focusing at all